# Find the radius of convergence given a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question:** Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty 3^{k^2}x^{k^2} $.

**Attempt:** By the root test $\lim_{k\to\infty} |3^{k^2} x^{k^2}|^{1/k} = \lim_{k\to\infty}|3^k x^k| = \lim_{k\to\infty}|3x|^{1/k} $. This limit exists when $|3x| < 1$

So $R = 1/3$.

Is this correct? Please can someone help. Thank you

Comment: Basically correct: $|3x|^{1/k}$ should be $|3x|^k$, but I assume that's just a typo.  Perhaps you should give some more detail by mentioning that $|3x|^k$ tends to $0$ if $|3x|<1$ and to $\infty$ if $|3x|>1$.

Comment: This is [Jacobi's elliptic $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).